# right click menu using both key board and mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some java script right click menu using both key board and mouse.

have any one seen a good plug in?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, to detect the right click you can do:

```
$('body').bind('mousedown', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        // Create menu here
    }
});
```

To detect a certain key:

```
$('body').bind('keydown', function(event) { 
    if (event.which == //some key code, like 70) {
        // Create menu here
    }
});
```

Comment: @kasie:I would like to bring data from mysql db and list out here as menu.Give me a snippet.I do not know about key codes

Comment: Note that context menus don't typically appear on mousedown - they usually require a complete click (mousedown, mouseup).

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu and I always get a context on simple mousedown.

Comment: event.which == 92 gives keyboard right click.. You could use this tool to test things out : http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 0):

have a look at these plugins...

[right click plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/right-click-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `oncontextmenu` event, which is supported by every major browser except Opera.  This will fire for the right-click and keyboard context menu if you want to display your own:

```
$("#myDiv").bind("contextmenu", function () {
    $("#menu").show();
    return false;
});
```

Note that Firefox users can expressly disable context menu overriding.  For Opera, you'd have to bind to the `click` event and necessary key combinations (which may vary between operating systems).